# WordPress get product by taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have created 7 WooCommerce products under 'membership-level' category. Now, to get those products I am using the following code but not working as expected.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'membership-level',
        )
    )
];

echo '<pre>';
print_r( get_posts( $args ) );
echo '</pre>';
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query products by product category you have to set

- taxonomy name: in your case "product_cat"
- field (p.ex: term_id, slug): in your case slug
- and term

So try something like that

```php
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(

            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('membership-level')

    )
];

echo '<pre>';
print_r( get_posts( $args ) );
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Oh, Yes, this is working fine :) Thank You.

Comment: Can you tell me which function I should use to get the product price, title etc ?

Comment: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/